# What does [FAILED] Failed unmounting /cdrom mean during installation?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

When I clicked reboot now, it took me to the command prompt screen and there one of line was

`[FAILED] Failed unmounting /cdrom`

[image: Failed unmounting /cdrom]

Now I can't even use my keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Looks like Hyper-V, your VM attempted to eject the drive but the host didn't respond in a way it understood. It may have been ejected, but if it didn't you will need to manually eject it using the host